# Show logs stored in ElasticSearch On Grafana

Tags: elasticsearch, metrics, syslog, grafana, graylog2

I use ElasticSeearch and GrayLog to show and analyse logs, this solution is great, but I want to replace grayLog by Grafana, I see that it can do a lot of greate Graphes, but I dont found any solution to show logs on Grafana.

I wont to collect syslogs and author logs, also metrics from system Parse and store theme on ElasticSearch, and finaly show both of theme on Grafana, logs and métrics.

If you have a suggestion or a solluttion for that, please help me.